# SQL query with multiple tables?

Tags: sql, join

I'm looking to get information from one table, use that to then get data from a 2nd table and then reference the data from the 2nd table to get all relevant fields. i.e:

**Table1**:

```
ID 
--
69
```

**Table2**:

```
entity_id | id
----------------
69        | 134
```

**Table3**:

```
id  | postcode | cost
----------------------
134 | m21 6fh  | 850
```

I need to do this for each entry in `table1`. I have been trying to use the LEFT JOIN which works until I hit the third table.

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
Select t1.*, t2.*, t3.* from table1
left join table2 on t1.id = t2.id
left join table3 on t1.id = t3.id -- change to t2.id = t3.id if you want to fetch only when id exists in table2
```

Note, result will alter if you will use inner join at any place, or use `t2.id = t3.id` instead of `t1.id = t3.id` to join on third table.

Answer (score 0):

Try simply in this way:

```
SELECT Table3.* FROM Table1, Table2, Table3
WHERE table1.ID = table2.EntityId
AND table3.id = table2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this not work?

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
  LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.entity_id
  LEFT JOIN table3 ON table2.ID = table3.ID
```

Note: you will only get table3 data if you have table2 data, which is unavoidable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*, t3.* FROM Table1 t1
  LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.entity_id = t1.id
  LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.id = t2.id
```